# Should we further qualify which software questions are on topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

We have specified in our [welcome message](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/welcome-to-economics-se) that software questions related to economics and econometrics software are on topic, and it's been a topic discussed [before](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/are-software-questions-on-topic).

[This question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/33293/simultaneous-equations-models-in-r), however, left me wondering whether or not we should perhaps further qualify what software questions we consider on topic. More specifically, should we require a certain level of effort or "question level", as we do in homework questions?

Part of the linked question above seems like stuff one would be able to find in the help file of the software package, although I may be wrong there.

In any case I feel that questions of the type "How do I carry out a linear regression in R/Stata/SPSS" and "How do I interpret the coefficient of a linear regression" would be off-topic as it is information that can be found all over the web and is supposedly covered in any basic statistics/econometrics course.

Then again, this is a slippery slope as the follow-up question becomes "How high do we need to set the bar?" In addition we do not seem to get too many of these questions in the first place, so perhaps further qualification is overdoing it.